# Add and reload buttons for an OS X app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, button

I have a working OS X app, but I need to add "Add" and "Reload" buttons to the Navigation Bar.
And I really wants buttons like in GitHub app, here is the [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/Cps6+).

I found NSAddTemplate and NSRefreshTemplate, but they aren't so nice.

UPD1: The solution is really easy: I added a NSButton and use NSRefreshTemplate as button image

Comment: The image templates appear to be what you want based on this screenshot, what exactly is wrong with the outcome thus far?

Comment: They are in silver rounded box.

Comment: Oh my god, the solution is so easy: I added the NSButton and used NSRefreshTemplate for a button image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really easy: add a Rounded Textured NSButton and use NSRefreshTemplate as button image

Answer (score 1):

You can design toolbar item templates using custom views inside IB; The appropriate controls can be dragged on the toolbar in the outline view and it'll generate the custom view for you, then you can tweak the control to have the appropriate named image, etc.

[image]

Comment: The solution is really easy: I added a NSButton and use NSRefreshTemplate as button image

Answer (score 0):

In order to create custom buttons, you'll need to provide the images yourself and draw them  by subclassing NSButtonCell and overriding drawWithFrame:inView:.

Comment: I know how to create custom buttons, I just think that this buttons are system ones, and I can find them somewhere. But ok, I can make an silver box and put NSReloadTemplate in it.

Comment: The solution was really easy: I added a NSButton and use NSRefreshTemplate as button image